# getSupportFragmentManager() method is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a Main activity which extends `SherlockActivity`

The following code seems to be giving me trouble

```
PopularFragment fragment = new PopularFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                           .commit();
```

I get the error "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`"

I tried getSupportFragmentManager() but that gives me this error "`The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Main.DrawerItemClickListener`"

I am playing with the new android navigation drawer, in my libs/ folder I only have `support library v13`

my fragments imports are import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

How do I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: You should extend SherlockFragmentActivity not SherlockActivity. And call getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager.

Comment: @Lingviston add your comment to answer section. It was helpful..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` not `SherlockActivity`. And call `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is a good practice, But I have changed with `newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");`
And the datePicker is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
YourActivityClassName.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
```